# Right to Left layout support is causing warning lints in xml editor

Tags: android, xml, layout, right-to-left, lint

Recently I updated to the new ADT plugin. Since then whenever I'm creating an xml layout using any tag like

```
android:layout_toRightOf="  " 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and basically anything with the word left and right a lint warning shows telling me to add start and end tags for every left and right tag I use in order to support right to left layouts.

for example it suggests I change the previous xml to

```
android:layout_toRightOf="  " 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="  " 
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Is anyone having the same issue ? Is there a way to either have the eclipse xml editor add these tags automatically as I move a view inside a layout or just to disable these lints or feature completely ?
I tried declaring in my manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

in order to disable the feature but that line needs api 17+ and my app supports api 9+.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Same here. And for me it is not just warnings, but errors! So I can't compile my code without cleaning it first, to get rid of these "errors". And it annoys me, because every build after a cleaning take ages to finish!!

Comment: @dum4ll3 take a look at the answer and comments below and you will fix it :)

Comment: I might had expressed me wrong. But I just wanted to point out that for me, it isn't just warnings, but errors (with the red x  mark, even if I disable lint checking). Otherwise, I would just ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you declared `android:targetSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file with a value of **17** or higher, then you'll also need to declare `android:layout_toEndOf` and `android:layout_toStartOf` to support right-to-left display.

But, if your `android:targetSdkVersion` is **16** or lower, you can ignore the Lint warning as it does not affect the development or deployment of your application.

Comment: I am using target 9 and higher. My problem is that the warnings annoy me:p not that they affect the development.

Comment: is there a way to at least hide them ?

Comment: For Eclipse, select **Window | Preferences | Android | Lint Error Checking** and disable the option to check for Lint errors. Be careful with this though, because if you deploy an app with other errors besides the warnings, you'll will _not_ be notified.

Comment: I see. Do you know a way to selectively disable only the lints I want ?

Comment: Look for Id `Bi-directional Text` and select **Ignore** where applicable. I'm not sure which option is correct, but you could try `RtlCompat`, or `RtlEnabled`.

Comment: The tag is RtlSymmetry and it removed the lints. Note that after changing the lint settings you need to restart eclipse and clean every project. Thanks

Comment: @Diffy: Some languages (like Hebrew and Arabic) read right to left instead of left to right.